# Can a view in SQL Server be updatable if its based on a table and another view?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a view that joins a table and another view and I have created an `instead of insert` trigger on this view; but when I try to insert a row into this view, the program shows an error:

> Invalid object name

for the name of view in insert statement

Comment: Can you post your view, table, and trigger definitions, and insert statement, please?

Comment: If you have views that join to other views you have created yourself a nightmare. It seems so logical to do this but in reality it is one of the worst things you can do for performance. https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/the-seven-sins-against-tsql-performance/#seven In other words, you don't want to pursue this, you want to rewrite your views so they aren't nested.